# Can't migrate to any site except meta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I voted to close a question, and felt that it's more appropriate on another site, but when I opened the off topic "dialog" it offers only the option to migrate to meta. Is it a matter of lacking privileges or a bug?

I checked the Help, and the privileges section doesn't mention anything about migration privileges.

[image]

Comment: We never had any migration paths unlocked, or?

Comment: We didn't. But before it seemed that migration is just something that non-mod users can't do. Now, there is a migration GUI that is empty, this is bothering. It like putting a unpushable button and writing "push button for candy"

Comment: Migrating to meta is sometimes useful.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done the research to use the correct terms here, but...

Non-mods can only recommend migrations to common destinations, that are manually unlocked.
Skeptics.SE has never had any such destinations (apart from meta) unlocked. There aren't any common migration paths.

If a question is flagged with a suggestion for migration, we tend to manually consult the mods of the destination site to make sure it is appropriate (unless we know it well), because many sites are sensitive about having poor questions dumped on them, rather than closed

Comment: Is there any way that we can get a generic comment area under the "Off-topic > Migration" selection though? There are cases when something should likely be migrated and flagging it as other doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: Good idea. This was the [closest I could find](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109740/could-normal-users-have-an-easier-way-to-flag-for-migration) so I upvoted it.

Comment: Just upvoted it myself as well.